why does my line graph look like this, seems like boxes rather than lines?
Here's what it looks like:

I'm getting boxes rather than lines in the plot.
This was the syntax, I can't find where the mistake is.
fig2 = px.line(df,x="Year",y="Victims_of_Rape_Total",color='Area_Name')

I tried reading the official documentation but couldn't find a solution.

You're just talking about the yellow lines? I suspect you have zero valuesfor that area that cause it to keep dropping. Please post a sample dataframe.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
